# Parsing definitions in json format from Wikipedia API in php

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.3

I was trying to build a script that could get me definitions of words from the wikipedia API in php. 
I tried several obtaining the definitions in an array and displaying the first definition but it didn't work. Can anyone please help me out. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please provide the code of your own try to the question, so we can help you. A sample JSON with the structure might help aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which parameters did you use in your request?

You can take this as an example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=PHP&limit=1&format=json

You said there that you want only the first definition, so you can put `limit=1`. The response is in json.

Comment: This one nailed it. Thanks, its all I needed